# Android Plugin with foreground service for Unity3D

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

i am trying to write an android plugin for Unity3D. The plugin should start a foreground service that can not be stoped after killing app using a notification channel. I wrote some code but it does not work.
I have 2 questions:

1. How can i put my Unity Activity context into my onStartCommand here (instead Bridge class)
   `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Bridge.class);`?
2. Can i actually start a notification in class that derives form Application class?

### Service Class

```
public class PedometerService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Bridge.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent,0);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "PedometerLib")
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_adb)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1,notification);
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

### Application Class

```
public class Bridge extends Application {

public static final String TAG="channelExample";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    createNotifficationChannel();

}


private void createNotifficationChannel(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "PedometerLib",
                "Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        if (manager!=null){
            Log.d("START", "NOT NULL");
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }

    }
}

public void ExecuteService(final Context ctx,final String message){
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(ctx, PedometerService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra","Service works...");
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,serviceIntent);
    ctx.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

}
```

Comment: try to add to your "It does not work", your debug logs to facilitate the search please ^^

Comment: you cant extend application in plugin, extend UnityPlayerActivity and start your service from it. To extend UPA just add classes.jar from your unity version to your project